# Copying Excel data to Oracle Applications form

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I'm new to moving Excel data to external programs using VBA or anything else for that matter. I've done some research, but I couldn't find any real answers to what I'm trying to do.

On an Excel worksheet, I have multiple (anywhere from 1-maybe 1,000) rows beginning on row 84. of measurement information: Last name, first name, gender, height, weight, etc. I need to get those in an Oracle Applications form.

This is the code I created, and it does the job, but it will only process the first row. In addition to the measurement rows, an initial row of data must be processed as well. I put in line breaks in the code to try to show where each line in the Oracle form is laid out. Also, each row begins with a different number. It starts at 10 and increases in increments of 10.

The long string of tabs is necessary to get to another set of columns in the form. If you were doing this manually, you would use the dropdown menu, but I don't think that's possible in VBA. Is it possible? Or would it be better to do this using something other than VBA?

```
Sub MoveToOracle()
    AppActivate "Oracle Applications - cbsProd (11.5.10.2)"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    SendKeys ("10")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("A")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("E1")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("ENV")
    SendKeys ("{DOWN}")

    SendKeys ("20")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("1")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("FN{F3}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("A2")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("B2")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("C2")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("D2")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("E2")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("F2")
    SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    SendKeys Range("G2")
End Sub
```

[image]

Edit: The Read Order number will not be read from the Excel workbook. Each new row will need to begin with a unique number in increments of 10, starting at 10. I'm not sure how to loop through the Excel data with SendKeys.

Also, I'm pretty much stuck using Excel. I do not have dev access to create or manage databases.

Comment: Is there a database behind the oracle form? Is it possible to get the information into the database via export/import, and then fill out the form from within its database? Writing data "manually" via VBA into a oracle form seems kind of overly complicated to me.

Comment: There is, but I can't get access to it. Is it possible/better to do what I'm trying to do with something other than VBA?

Comment: That depends.. what exactly are you trying to do? What happenes, after you wrote data into that form?

Comment: I have an order form of sorts on an Excel worksheet. I need that data to end up in this Oracle form. The image I posted is the result of the code.

Comment: That is the end goal? Just the data in the form? Not it being saved in some form (e.g. oracle db)?

Comment: No. I just need the data from the worksheet into this Oracle form.

Comment: It would be much easier if you exported the data into a db and then read the data from the db into the form, avoiding VBA entirely.

Comment: I don't have access to the db.

Comment: I can't get dev access to create even a temporary db. I'm stuck with this Oracle form and Excel, basically.

Comment: Good edit at the end! For more on how to use loops in VBA see the links in my answer below.

Comment: not intimately familiar with oracle, can you grab window names using ms windows api?.... regarding the drop down menu, most likely yes because drop down are usually done with mouse. get cords of the menu, send the mouse to those coords, send a click, move the mouse again, another click. if it's always in the same place you should be able to do it. using the clipboard will likely be advantageous if caution is used. I'd also try using the recommended method over send keys if possible

Answer (score 0):

There is, as far as I know, no public API for VBA available to interact with an oracle form, so your best bet might very well be this way.

Edit:

To iterate through your worksheet, you need to create some kind of [counter](http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_do_loops.html) and/or [loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/do-loop-statement).

Edit:

Alternatively you could create a temporary db for this. Export the data from your excel sheet to that temporary database, then read the data out from it. There is an export function built into excel, and the form should easily be filled with an oracle database behind it.

Comment: Okay, but I'm going to need to loop through the rows and increment the Read Order numbers, and I'm not sure how to do that with SendKeys.

Comment: Can you increment the read order numbers with your keyboard only within the form?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter. How else could it be done?

Comment: Added another proposal to my answer.

Comment: I'm not able to create a temporary db.

Comment: I am afraid that if your company can't provide you with the necessary permissions to use other technologies like a temp oracle db, you are stuck with VBA. Try to loop over those rows with your code. If you update your question with details on that "Read Order number", I might be able to help you with that as well. Update your code with what you have tried when you get stuck on the code for the loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub MoveToOracle()
    '   Oracle Applications Forms is a java VM window
    '   VBA code interaction with Controls within the VM window is by the use of sendkeys
    '   One commercial alternate application is Data Load.
    '
    AppActivate "Oracle Applications - cbsProd (11.5.10.2)"
    '   API SetForegroundWindow preferred over AppActivate
    Text string for 1 st row in Oracle Applications
    Let  Field_Text = "10" & "{TAB}" & "A" & "{TAB}" & Range("E1").Value & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "{TAB}" & "ENV" & "{DOWN}"
    '   When using sendkeys the NUMLOCK is toggled on / off with each call of SendKeys
    '   NUMLOCK ON
    Let  SendKeysString = Field_Text & "{NUMLOCK}"
    SendKeys Field_Text
    '   Preferred dedicated pause sub using API sleep
    '   Author Kevin zorvek Posted on 2007-06-22 http://www.experts-exchange.com/
    '   Pause 0.6 seconds here for Oracle Applications before continuing
    '   Allows for Oracle Applications to catch up
    '   NUMLOCK ON
    '   Place pause code here
    Let  SendKeysString = vbNullString
    AppActivate "Oracle Applications - cbsProd (11.5.10.2)"
    '   Text string for 2 nd row in Oracle Applications
    Let  Field_Text = ""     ' Empty variable
    Let  Field_Text = "20" & "{TAB}" & "1" & "{TAB}" & "FN{F3}" & "{TAB}" & Range("A2").Value & "{TAB}" & Range("B2").Value
    Let  Field_Text = Field_Text & "{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}"
    Let  Field_Text = Field_Text & Range("C2").Value & "{TAB}" & Range("D2").Value & "{TAB}" & Range("E2").Value & "{TAB}" & Range("F2").Value & "{TAB}" & Range("F2").Value
    Let  Field_Text = Field_Text & "{NUMLOCK}"
    SendKeys Field_Text
    '   Pause 0.6 seconds here for Oracle Applications before continuing
    '   Allows for Oracle Applications to catch up
    '   NUMLOCK ON
    '   Place pause code here
    Let SendKeysString = vbNullString
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).